# Cant upgrade Angular from 6 to 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

When i fire `ng update` it shows two entries for `@angular/core`.
and when i fire `ng update @angular/core` it goes to 8 form 6

```
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 99 dependencies.
Two or more projects are using identical roots. Unable to determine project using current working directory. Using default workspace project instead.
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cdk                       6.4.7 -> 8.2.2           ng update @angular/cdk
      @angular/core                      6.1.10 -> 8.2.9          ng update @angular/core
      @angular/core                      6.1.10 -> 7.2.15         ng update @angular/core
      @angular/material                  6.4.7 -> 8.2.2           ng update @angular/material
```

Comment: Here it shows you're going to 8 ...

Comment: Yeah but few of our libraries don't support 8. I want to upgrade to 7.

Comment: [`--to` might help](https://angular.io/cli/update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the version or it will update to the latest version.

ng update @angular/cli@7.0.0 @angular/core@7.0.0

There may be further changes you need to make before updating.

Please see this link for more info https://update.angular.io/#6.0:7.0